# Oracle column comment.

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm looking for a solution that would let me specify the Oracle column comment in the mapping file. Below is an attempt using  but I got that error...

21:13:38.714 DEBUG [SchemaExport.Execute] Sistema: comment on column Cone_Slab.Id_Cone_Slab IS 'Identificador do registro'; comment on column Cone_Slab.Id_Slab IS 'Identificador da 
placa'; 
21:13:38.734 WARN [SchemaExport.Execute] Sistema: Unsuccessful: comment on column cone_Slab.Id_Cone_Slab IS 'Identificador do registro'; comment on column Cone_Slab.Id_Slab IS 'Identificador da placa'; 
21:13:38.735 WARN [SchemaExport.Execute] Sistema: ORA-00911: caractere inválido

```
 <class name="ConeSlab" table="Cone_Slab" lazy="false"> 
    <id name="Id" column="Id_Cone_Slab" type="Int32"> 
      <generator class="hilo"/> 
    </id> 
    <many-to-one name="Cone" column="Id_Cone" class="Cone" cascade="none" fetch="join" not-null="true"/> 
    <many-to-one name="Slab" column="Id_Slab" class="Slab" cascade="none" fetch="join" not-null="true"/> 
  </class> 
  <database-object> 
    <create>comment on column Cone_Slab.Id_Cone IS 'Identificador do cone'; comment on column Cone_Slab.Id_Slab IS 'Identificador da placa';</create> 
    <drop></drop> 
  </database-object>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using two separate `<database-object>` elements, one per comment.